# Given $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that $\frac{df}{dx}=4$ at the point $(2,3)$ and $\frac{df}{dx}=-2$ at $(-1,0)$, find the constants $a, b$ and $c$.

Tags: derivatives, quadratics

Please help with this question.
Given that a function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is such that $\frac{df}{dx}=4$ at the point $(2,3)$ and $\frac{df}{dx}=-2$ at the point $(-1,0)$, find the value of the constants $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: What have you tried? Were you able to find df/dx in terms of a,b,c?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = ax^2 + bx+c$$
$$\frac{df}{dx} = 2ax+b$$
Substituting $\frac{df}{dx} = 4$ at $x=2$ $$2a(2) + b = 4$$
Substituting $\frac{df}{dx} = -2$ at $x=-1$ $$2a(-1) + b = -2$$
Solving the simultaneous equations, $a=1$, $b=0$, $f(x) = x^2 + c$ $$$$Substituting $(2,3)$: $$f(2) =2^2 + c = 3$$And so $c=-1$, making $f(x) = x^2-1$

Comment: Please refrain from answering low-quality/contextless questions.